# Android MediaRecorder stop error

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a voice recording app using the emulator - API21. I wrote my code in a way that the voice recording code portion is in another java file rather reside in the UI activity there. When I click on the start button, no error occurs and from the logs, it seems that recording has started. However, the app crashes after I click on the stop button. Do you know what I have done wrong here?

Logcat

```
    07-19 15:22:53.180    1312-1476/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
    07-19 15:22:53.290      953-953/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 2062 for session 8
    07-19 15:22:53.310      953-953/? I/MPEG4Writer﹕ limits: 4294967295/0 bytes/us, bit rate: 12200 bps and the estimated moov size 3072 bytes
    07-19 15:22:53.320     953-3278/? I/MediaCodecSource﹕ MediaCodecSource (audio) started
    07-19 15:22:53.340     953-3280/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ RecordThread: buffer overflow
    07-19 15:22:53.360     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.370     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.380     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.400     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.410     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.420     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.430     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.440     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.450     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.470     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.480     953-3286/? I/MPEG4Writer﹕ setStartTimestampUs: 40000
    07-19 15:22:53.480     953-3286/? I/MPEG4Writer﹕ Earliest track starting time: 40000
    07-19 15:22:53.490     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:53.530     953-3279/? W/AudioSource﹕ AudioRecord reported overrun!
    07-19 15:22:54.950     953-1286/? D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Audio track stopping
    07-19 15:22:54.950     953-1286/? D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Audio track source stopping
    07-19 15:22:54.960    1312-1476/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
    07-19 15:22:54.970     953-3278/? I/MediaCodecSource﹕ encoder (audio) stopped
    07-19 15:22:55.000     953-1284/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ write blocked for 1470 msecs, 1 delayed writes, thread 0xf62b7000
            --------- beginning of crash
    07-19 15:22:55.080      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    07-19 15:22:55.080      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86_64/sdk_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.0.2/LSY64/1772600:eng/test-keys'
    07-19 15:22:55.080      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
    07-19 15:22:55.080      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'x86_64'
    07-19 15:22:55.080      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 2062, tid: 2070, name: Binder_1  >>> ch.com.voiceme <<<
    07-19 15:22:55.080      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdead4321
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ rax 0000000000000004  rbx 0000000000000004  rcx 00007f8c53c714b8  rdx 0000000000000001
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ rsi 000000000000186d  rdi 000000007035c240
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8  0000000000000000  r9  000000007144d434  r10 000000007144d434  r11 00007f8c53c716d8
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ r12 00000000dead4321  r13 0000000000000000  r14 00000000719a59d4  r15 000000007035c240
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ rip 00007f8c61ae607c  rbp 00007f8c5ac2e800  rsp 00007f8c53c71360  eflags 0000000000010206
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 00000000000b507c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::CheckMethodArguments(art::mirror::ArtMethod*, unsigned int*)+629)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 000000000033b0b6  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+1094)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 0000000000273c2d  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+397)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 000000000011b284  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+132)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 0000000000021ae5  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+133)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 000000000003bd54  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (JNIMediaRecorderListener::notify(int, int, int)+68)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06 pc 00000000000dee01  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (android::MediaRecorder::notify(int, int, int)+145)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07 pc 00000000000d5efa  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (android::BnMediaRecorderClient::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+90)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08 pc 0000000000036b44  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+116)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09 pc 000000000003fea7  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+871)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10 pc 00000000000400f1  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+65)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11 pc 0000000000040169  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+89)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12 pc 0000000000047826  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+22)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13 pc 0000000000018eb8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+376)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14 pc 00000000000a6264  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+84)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15 pc 000000000002731e  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+46)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #16 pc 000000000002339b  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+11)
    07-19 15:22:55.130      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ #17 pc 0000000000019885  /system/lib64/libc.so (__bionic_clone+53)
    07-19 15:22:55.180      950-950/? I/DEBUG﹕ Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
    07-19 15:22:55.180    1312-1351/system_process I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    07-19 15:22:55.180    1312-2211/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl﹕ Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
    07-19 15:22:55.190    1312-3305/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception thrown during pause
            android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                            at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:701)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:852)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2754)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2611)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2453)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11511)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11408)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12087)
                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11603)
                            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
    07-19 15:22:55.190    1312-3305/system_process E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
    07-19 15:22:55.190    1312-3305/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Restarting because process died: ActivityRecord{78fabd1 u0 ch.com.voiceme/.VoiceMe t71}
    07-19 15:22:55.190    1312-3305/system_process E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
    07-19 15:22:55.210    1312-1441/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3bddbe08 ch.com.voiceme/ch.com.voiceme.AudioRecTimeSchedule (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
    07-19 15:22:55.210    1312-1441/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3bddbe08 ch.com.voiceme/ch.com.voiceme.AudioRecTimeSchedule (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    07-19 15:22:55.210    1312-1441/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '1c939c32 ch.com.voiceme/ch.com.voiceme.VoiceMe (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
    07-19 15:22:55.210    1312-1441/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '1c939c32 ch.com.voiceme/ch.com.voiceme.VoiceMe (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    07-19 15:22:55.260    1312-1732/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{1c939c32 u0 ch.com.voiceme/ch.com.voiceme.VoiceMe}
    07-19 15:22:55.260    1312-1732/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '1c939c32 ch.com.voiceme/ch.com.voiceme.VoiceMe (server)'
    07-19 15:22:55.270    1312-3305/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception when starting activity ch.com.voiceme/.VoiceMe
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void onRecord(boolean start) {

    if (start) {
        audioRec.startRecording();}
    else {audioRec.stopRecording();}
}

private void onPlay(boolean start) {
    if (start) { audioRec.startPlaying(); }
    else { audioRec.stopPlaying(); }
}
```

AudioRecord.java

```
public AudioRecord() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("path", mFileName);
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    }

public void startPlaying() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}

public void stopPlaying() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void startRecording() {
    try {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

public void stopRecording() {
    try {
        mRecorder.stop();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException ex){ Log.e("testttt", ex.getMessage()); /* Ignore */ }

    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.reset();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
```

}

Comment: Similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829102/audioflinger59-recordthread-buffer-overflow-when-activity-is-paused

Comment: Interesting -- native crash inside the Art runtime, at address 0xdead4321 . Could be a deliberate crash, like an assert(), though traditionally such things are preceded by helpful log messages. So more likely a deliberate bad value left lying around to cause a specific failure if someone tries to dereference it.

Comment: So do I need to add extend the threads class in my AudioRecord. java file or is there anything wrong with the code? The weird thing is if I combine all the codes into the MainActivity. java file,  I can run with no errors.  Doing it modularly seems to have this error.  Am trying to understand what did I do wrong here

Comment: Wait so you're not using any threads or anything? You just moved the code into another class? That should be the exact same thing if you're not using a background thread?  Also you can print a stacktrace by passing Log.e("tag", "msg", ex) to have it print the stacktrace. I think that by catching runtimeexception you might be disguising a larger issue.