# Unable to play recorded raw PCM from file

Tags: android

I have saved recorded audio raw PCM into a file rxrawpcm.pcm, after that i tried to play the pcm file but unable to play recorded PCM? I didn't hear recorded voice hearing only a buzzy sound

Configuration

AudioRecorder and AudioTrack  configuration

```
Stream Type     :STREAM_VOICE_CALL
Sample Rate     : 8000
Audio Format    :PCM_16BIT
MODE        :MODE_STREAM
Channel Config  :CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO
```

**Recording**

```
byte[] buffer=new byte[1600];
int read = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,buffer.length);
if(recordAudio){
if(out!=null){
out.write(buffer);
}
```

Player Side

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(rxFile);
byte[] buffer=new byte[1600];

while(fis.read(buffer)!=-1){
audioPlayer.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
}
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the sample rate, bit depth, number of channels (usually mono/interleaved stereo) and endian-ness are all consistent in order to play back the data.

Comment: hi can u check my question once again

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer size may be too small. You are supposed to use the getMinBufferSize method to determine the smallest buffer size that doesn't result in buffer overflows. The top voted answer in this question [Android AudioRecord class - process live mic audio quickly, set up callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525206/android-audiorecord-class-process-live-mic-audio-quickly-set-up-callback-func) demonstrates how to properly setup audio recording with an appropriate buffer size.

Comment: Actually i am able to play audio loop back. But only when it comes to playing from file it give's me trouble.i have set buffer size  to 8320.

Comment: It also looks like you are writing the entire read buffer, when you should be using the read count to write only the number of bytes you have read. `out.write(buffer, 0, read);`

Comment: this is a simple task but i dono why i am not getting the right output