# What codec is used for audiodata from AudioRecord.read() in android

Tags: android, audio, stream, codec, audiorecord

Audio data is saved in the same way as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525206/android-audiorecord-class-process-live-mic-audio-quickly-set-up-callback-func):

```
// 1. create AudioRecord instance
// 2. audioTrack.play();

    // 3. in separate thread reading into buffer
    // int bytesRead = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
    // 4. save buffer to file
    // fio.write(buffer, 0 , bytesRead);

// 4. audioTrack.stop();
```

What codec/format is used as saved file can't be opened as WAV file, but can be read and played using AudioTrack class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No codec is used. It reads raw samples. If you want to save to .wav file you should first write  a [.wav header](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) to file.Look at this [example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/audio-recording-in-wav-format-in-android-programming/)

Answer (score 0):

No codec is used, if you are looking for some kind of codec, I advise you to try: [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. i can't use MediaRecorder as i have to save into OutputStream and MediaRecorder saved to file only.

Comment: @user1103561: Not necessarily. You can pass a `FileDescriptor` to the `setOutputFile` method. That `FileDescriptor` could correspond to e.g. a socket.

Comment: Great to know. But it still does not allow to output data in a stream (any OutputStream).