# Decoding audio with Jspeex in android produces choppy/clipped sound

Tags: android, audio, live-streaming, speex, jspeex

i am developing an android app, which plays live speex audio stream. So i used jspeex [library](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/) .
The audio stream is 11khz,16 bit.
At android side i have done as follows:

```
SpeexDecoder decoder = new SpeexDecoder();
decoder.init(1, 11025,1, true);
decoder.processData(subdata, 0, subdata.length);
byte[] decoded_data =  new byte[decoder.getProcessedDataByteSize()];
int result= decoder.getProcessedData(decoded_data, 0);
```

When this decoded data is played by Audiotrack , some part of audio is clipped.
Also when decoder is set to nb-mode( first parameter set to 0) the sound quality is worse.
I wonder there is any parameter configuration mistake in my code.
Any help, advice appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Sampling rate and buffer size should be set in an optimized way for the specific device**. For example you can use [AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getMinBufferSize(int,%20int,%20int)) to obtain the best size for your buffer:

```
   int sampleRate = 11025; //try also different standard sampleRate
   int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

If your `Audiotrack` has a buffer which is too small or too large you will experience audio glitch. I suggest you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525206/android-audiorecord-class-process-live-mic-audio-quickly-set-up-callback-func) and play around with these values (*sampleRate* and *bufferSize*).

Comment: I have set 11025 because the incoming audio is of 11 KHz,, also i have tried with different standard frequencies and buffer size.. but quality is not improving