# Android how to record audio and post to server at the same time with interval?

Tags: android

I need to record audio and then send the recorded clip to server every 5 seconds. For example, at 5 seconds after recording started, you will send 5 seconds clip. Another 5 seconds after, it will send total 10 seconds clip from the start to the end.

How can I do?

I'm following this [Android AudioRecord class - process live mic audio quickly, set up callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525206/android-audiorecord-class-process-live-mic-audio-quickly-set-up-callback-func)

However, it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't need to send the audio in real time, why don't you record the whole audio file first, and then split it into increments of 5 seconds? You could then send all these files to the server.

Comment: I need to send in real time.